# Installing Python3 OpenCV3 using conda on linux-32

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.0, conda

I have python 3.5.1 installed with anaconda 2.4.1 on a 32-bit linux (Ubuntu 14).  I'm trying to install openCV (3.1.0), using conda without any luck so far..

The 'menpo' channel (https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3) doesn't have a linux-32 version, and while installing through the 'msarahan' channel (https://anaconda.org/msarahan/opencv):

```
conda install —channel https://conda.anaconda.org/msarahan opencv
```

resulted in the following error when trying to `import cv2` in python:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)
```

Any suggestions how should I proceed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by downloading it from binstar. Here's what I tried to install it into the environment `env_name`

`conda install -n <env_name> -c https://conda.binstart.org/menpo opencv`

and in the python shell

```
>>> import cv2
```